# Wildfly 11 Elytron - Properties File Based Authentication failing with required services not installed

Tags: wildfly

I have a new instance of Wildfly 11, where I am trying to setup Properties File Based Authentication within Elytron.  I'm using the Standalone-full.xml and manually deploying the application outside of an IDE.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Properties+File+Based+Authentication+Migration

I created the myApp-user and myApp-roles properties files with name valued pairs and included #$REALM_NAME=myAppPropRealm$

I ran the following CLI commands to create the

## Create Prop Realm

/subsystem=elytron/properties-realm=myAppPropRealm:add(groups-attribute=groups,groups-properties={path=myApp-roles.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir},users-properties={path=myApp-users.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir,plain-text=true})

## Configure Security-Domain

/subsystem=elytron/security-domain=myAppSecurityDomain:add(realms=[{realm=myAppPropRealm,role-decoder=groups-to-roles}],default-realm=myAppPropRealm,permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper)

## Configure http-authentication-factory

/subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=myApp-http-auth:add(http-server-mechanism-factory=global,security-domain=myAppSecurityDomain,mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=myApp_ApplicationDomain}]}])

## Configure application-security-domain in Undertow

/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=myApp_ApplicationDomain:add(http-authentication-factory=myApp-http-auth)

JBoss-web.xml
    `</jboss-web>`
           `<security-domain>myApp_ApplicationDomain</security-domain>`
    `</jboss-web>`

I get the following error when my app tries to deploy

2018-11-29 09:06:55,695 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MyApplication-ws.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.myApp_ApplicationDomain"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [

I suspect it is because I have not defined 'myApp_ApplicationDomain' but this is where I'm stuck.  What commands do I run to add/reference
the myApp_ApplicationDomain?

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is looging for legacy security domain jboss.security.security-domain.myApp_ApplicationDomain for some reason. But seems you have correctly declared myApp_ApplicationDomain in undertow. Most probably you are using myApp_ApplicationDomain somewhere outside of undertow subsystem.